# queryBuilder.js

Tags: jquery, sql

I have some problems to set the local in the lib [queryBuilder.js](http://querybuilder.js.org) does one of you have made it correctly ?
And another question, is it possible to sync it to a database ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Browsers don't communicate directly with server side databases. You need to send data to server script

Comment: i know .... but with ajax you can, that's why i'm asking ....